# Recursion & Passing Ajax Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion

I'm trying to create a recursive $.ajax() caller, callARIs, which can run a number of $.ajax() calls based on input before the referenced callback function at the end of the sequence. This is intended to be run on form submission and is setup using 3 functions:

```
jQuery.fn.submitHandler = function(AjaxCallerInput,Callback){ 
        $(this).submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            //Validate & Gather Form Data

            if(!Valid){ /*ERROR*/ }
            else{ callARIs(AjaxCallerInput,formData,null,Callback); }
        }
}
function callARIs(Input,formData,i,Callback){

    //Process Input to create PostStr and define i if null

    $.ajax({ //Call ARI
        url: 'ajax.php', method: 'POST', async:true, data: PostStr + formData,
        complete: function(xhr){ 
            if(i < Input.length-1){ return callARIs(Input,poststr,i+1,sqi,Callback); }
            else{ return Callback(xhr.responseText); } 
        }
    });
}

function someCallback(){ //do stuff with final ajax result }

$("form").submitHandler("ARIstr",someCallback);
```

The Recursion and ajax calls all run as intended, the problem is that the Callback is "not a function" when it comes time to run it. I think this is being broken as a result of passing the reference through the recursion.
I am trying to find a way to make submitHandler be able to define the parameters for callARIs and the desired callback for the form submission. I could work around this by passing an index and writing logic to call the correct function in callARIs, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution that didn't require updating callARIs or submitHandler when new forms and callbacks are created.
Thanks in advance for any insight into how I could solve this issue.

Comment: It looks like `sqi` is being passed as the 4th parameter on recursive calls to `callARIs`. This effectively replaces your `Callback` param (and is probably not a function).

Comment: ...... now i just feel stupid....  but thanks none the less Kyle, I don't know how i missed this when I removed sqi as a required parameter

Comment: typos are always rough. no worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one extra parameter added in my recursive call overwrote the function reference, Thanks Kyle!